# publishing data from LabView through rosbridge(v2)

Tags: ros, rosbridge, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the ROS toolkit in LabView to publish an odometry message to a particular topic. When rosbridge(v2) is running I can see there is a connection between LabView and ROS(I am given a connection ID, while when rosbridge is not running i get 0). But there is no publishing of data to the topic, the topic does not appear in my topic list.

Any ideas of what could be the issue? According to clearpath robotics the only thing that needs to be done to connect labview and ROS on the ROS side is install the rosbridge. It might be though that the rosbridge is where the data gets stuck.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144631/publishing-data-from-labview-through-rosbridge(v2)/) by [av_roboticslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/13876/av_roboticslab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, the toolkit works with [rosbridge v1](http://rosbridge.org/doku.php?id=rosbridge_protocol_v1.0) only. My days have been a little too busy to upgrade, retest, and re-release everything.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [av_roboticslab](https://answers.ros.org/users/13876/av_roboticslab/) on 2014-03-27**:
thank you for responding. I was wondering whether you know of any way rosbridge v1 can run on hydro. In the documentation it says it works with versions up to and including groovy
I thought to give it a try but wasn't successful.